# Checking if a string contains values from a char array

Tags: java, python-3.x

It's been a while since I've programmed in java and today I was trying to refresh my memory on how to do things using it. (Because I'm getting ready for a java interview) I am trying to find vowels in a string containing a sentence and return how many vowels was found.

In python, here's how I did it.

```
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') #tuple containing vowels
sentence = "Refreshing my memory on java"
vowels_count = 0;
consonant_count = 0;
for s in sentence:
    if s in vowels:
        vowels_count += 1
    else:
        if s.isalpha():
            consonant_count += 1

print(vowels_count)
print(consonant_count)
```

I tried to do something similar in java but somehow my consonant count is always wrong. How can I fix it?

```
String sentence2 = "Refreshing my memory on java";
char[] lookout = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
int vowels = 0;
int consonants = 0;
for (int i=0; i < sentence2.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lookout.length; j++) {
            if (sentence2.charAt(i) == lookout[j]) {
                vowels++;
            } else {
                if (Character.isLetter(sentence2.charAt(j))) {
                    consonants++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

System.out.print(String.format("vowels count is %d consonant count is %d \n", vowels, consonants));
```

Comment: Always wrong? Can you post sample input, output

Comment: Why don't you use a List<String> for the vowels? That way you could write vowels.contains(sentence2.charAt(i))

Comment: use map for vowels instead

Comment: Y always sounded like a vowel to me so I thought it was but no consonant count returns 134 which is totally wrong.

Comment: You are incrementing consonants for every char for every non-vowel.

Comment: @ScaryWombat The OP's problem is here to ignore whitespaces

Comment: @user7 - you are right, I have edited my comment - the underlying problem still exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Character.isLetter(sentence2.charAt(j))`

The above must be

`Character.isLetter(sentence2.charAt(i))`

(j can vary only between 0 to 4. So you kept on picking the first four characters from your string)

<strike>Also, when did `y` become a vowel ;)</strike>

But you cannot do this within the for loop as you would count a consonant 5 times.

You can have a `flag` to denote if a vowel was found. If not you increment the consonants count

```
for (int i=0; i < sentence2.length(); i++) {
    boolean vowel = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < lookout.length; j++) {
        if (sentence2.charAt(i) == lookout[j]) {
            vowel = true;
            vowels++;
            break; //A vowel is found
        }
    }
    if (!vowel && Character.isLetter(sentence2.charAt(i))) {
        consonants++;
    }
}
```

A better way is to use a List or a Set and use `contains` method as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49526036/4405757).

Comment: Thanks, your way works. Although I still find it strange that my logic on python works while the same type of logic doesn't work in java even if I replace J with I as it should have been.

Comment: That's because when you do `s in vowels` its equivalent to `someSet.contains(s)`. But here, you are looping through each vowel and hence you should not increment the consonant count for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest approach would be to create a set of vowel characters, so you can query whether a character is a vowel easily.

Something like this should work (I haven't tested it, so there may be minor errors)

```
final Set<Character> vowel_set = Set.of('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y');
int vowels = 0;
int consonants = 0;
for (int i=0; i < sentence2.length(); i++) {

    if (vowel_set.contains(sentence2.charAt(i))) {vowels++;}
    else if (Character.isLetter(sentence2.charAt(i))) {consonants++;}

}
```

Comment: It would be good to specify that this will work only in Java 9+.

Answer (score 1):

Use any of the already provided answers (I'd say [Antimony's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49526036/2832479) answer is what I'd have done myself). To avoid counting whitespace, and take uppercase vowels into account, you could do:

```
String fixedStr = sentence2.replace(" ", "").trim().toLowerCase();
```

And then use `fixedStr` when you do your `#charAt(int)` checks.

However, using [Anitmony's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49526036/2832479) answer, it would be

```
String sentence2 = "Refreshing my memory on java";
String fixedStr = sentence2.replace(" ", "").trim().toLowerCase();

Set<Character> lookout = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'));

int vowels = 0;
int consonants = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < fixedStr.length(); i++) {
    if(lookout.contains(fixedStr.charAt(i))) vowels++;
    else consonants++;
}

System.out.print(String.format(
            "total characters to check is %d (%d with whitespace), vowels " +
            "count is %d, consonant count is %d, which adds up to %d \n",
            fixedStr.length(), sentence2.length(), vowels, consonants,
            vowels + consonants));
```

`Set<Character> lookout = new TreeSet(...)` can be replaced with `Set<Character> lookout = TreeSet.of('a'...);` in Java 9 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

First Convert the source string to lower or upper case.

```
/*Convert to lower case*/
sentence2 = sentence2.toLowerCase();
```

Now write a method to check for vowel or not.

```
/*Method for checking vowel or not*/
public static boolean isVowel(int ch) {
    if ("aeiou".indexOf(ch) < 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
Loop through your string and test the condition.

for (int i = 0; i < sentence2.length(); i++) {
    /*Check is character or not*/
    if (Character.isAlphabetic(sentence2.charAt(i))) {
        /*Check for vowel or not*/
        if (isVowel(sentence2.charAt(i))) {
            vowels++;
        } else {
            consonants++;
        }
    }

}
```

So the entire answer is like this.

```
public static boolean isVowel(int ch) {
    if ("aeiou".indexOf(ch) < 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public static void main(String...args) {
    String sentence2 = "Refreshing my memory on java";
    int vowels = 0;
    int consonants = 0;
    /*Convert to lower case*/
    sentence2 = sentence2.toLowerCase();

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence2.length(); i++) {
        /*Check is character or not*/
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(sentence2.charAt(i))) {
            /*Check for vowel or not*/
            if (isVowel(sentence2.charAt(i))) {
                vowels++;
            } else {
                consonants++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print(String.format("vowels count is %d consonant count is %d \n", vowels, consonants));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
} else {
    if (Character.isLetter(sentence2.charAt(j))) {
       consonants++;
   }
```

your basically just counting every letter as a consonant all you have to do is change that just say else consonant++

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user7 for his answer and explaination, I realized my mistake and managed to make my algorithm work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentence2.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lookout.length; j++) {
            if (sentence2.charAt(i) == lookout[j]) {
                vowels ++;
            }
        }
        if (Character.isLetter(sentence2.charAt(i))) {
            consonants++;
        }
    }
//subtracted vowel count from consonants :D
System.out.print(String.format("vowels count is %d consonant count is %d \n", vowels, consonants-vowels));
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing, you didn't take care of UPPERCASE.
Secondly, which there is sentence2[j] ?? Shouldn't be it as sentence2[i] in else block ? This is the issue

Comment: `#isLetter(char)` checks for uppercase as well.

Comment: I know. I called it for vowels. There is no UPPERCASE checking for vowels. Consonants are fine

Comment: I am new to Stack overflow, can you help me why there is -1? And why being the first person to answer, still I am not getting points ? I already went through tour. But it will be helpful, if anyone can explain the reason ?

Comment: Answering questions isn't a race. You don't get points for being first, second or last, you get points, if someone else find your answer to be worthy of an up-vote. In your case, it has probably received a down-vote for your incorrect statement "you didn't take care of UPPERCASE". `#isLetter(char)` checks for uppercase, _also_ on vowels.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But, I think the code for vowels is not using #isLetter. Please do check. I will be more careful to refer it more clearly in my answer only. But he is using == for vowels comparison. That's what I meant. But, thanks again. I will be more wary about clarity

Comment: The block of code increasing the vowel count did not need `Character.isLetter` the char array are all letters. If it's not matching anything in the char array, counter does not increase.